# Error cannot convert a DBNULL object to other C# Datagridview types

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to save the row of a datagridview in C# to sql, all good but the error pops up when I select the checkbox "for_collections", it should be noted that if it is false = 0 and if it is true = 1 I do not know what would be happening

> Error cannot convert a DBNULL object to other C#

[image]

```
public void mostrardatos() {

    dt = negCli.DatosContacto(MODULOS.Globales.Base, txtcod.Text.Trim());

    foreach(DataRow data in dt.Rows){

        int aa = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[0].Value = data["ITEM"].ToString();
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[1].Value = data["para_cobranza"].ToString();
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[2].Value = data["NOMBRE_CONTACTO"].ToString();
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[3].Value = data["DIRECCION_CONTACTO"].ToString();
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[4].Value = data["CORREO_CONTACTO"].ToString();
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[5].Value = data["TELEFONO_CONTACTO"].ToString();
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[aa].Cells[6].Value = data["DNI"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Save button

```
private void btnguardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save to db
    try
    {
        ClsCli.IdEmpresa = Globales.CodEmpresa;
        ClsCli.Codigo = txtcod.Text.Trim();
        ClsCli.ItemContacto =dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

        // el valor en Editar es null

        ClsCli.paracobrar =  **Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = DBNull.Value);**
                         
        ClsCli.Nombcontacto = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        ClsCli.DIRECCIONCONTACTO = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        ClsCli.CORREO_CONTACTO = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        ClsCli.TELEFONO_CONTACTO = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();

        ClsCli.Dni = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                      
        // ClsCli.paracobrar = Convert.ToInt32(doWork.Selected.ToString());

        negCli.Registrarcontactos(Globales.Base, ClsCli);
        MessageBox.Show("DATOS REGISTRADOR CORRECTAMENTE", "sistema S.A.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        mostrardatos();
        this.Close();
        //this.AGREGAR.Enabled = true;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex1) { MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message, "sistema S.A.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation); }
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "sistema S.A.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); }
    //this.button1.Enabled = false;
}
}
```

Here is the error

```
ClsCli.paracobrar =  Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = DBNull.Value);
```

But I don't know how to apply DBnull any suggestions?

Comment: Either put a constraint on the DB table to not allow nulls or coalesce the value with false. A checkbox can only show true or false. It does not know how to show DBNull.

Comment: Did you mean `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: if I meant == instead of =

Comment: Have you tried use boolean data type instead of integer? Do you realize that, according to the line of code, you are FIRST assigning DBNull to the cell value and THEN converting  DBNull to Int32, no matter the checkbox is checked or not? I don't get it.

Comment: logre solucionar este incoveniente solo agrege la siguiente linea ?? null;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem add the following line:

```
 ClsCli.paracobrar = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value ?? null);
```

Comment: `?? null` shouldn't be doing anything at all